# ios UIImagePickerController Take photo button title

Tags: ios, button, uiimagepickercontroller

I can take the photo by UIImagePickerController and the sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera ;

i want to know how to make the button title based on device language.

Now the cancel button, it only display "Cancel".
how can i make the cancel button base on difference langauge?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't unless you use a custom picker controller. I think it should change automatically based upon the device language but I think I am wrong on that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the following code, just change the Done title with cancel and provoke a dismissViewController:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

     UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@\"Done\"
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                            target:self 
                            action:@selector(saveImages:)];

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
   [bar setHidden:NO];
       ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
       ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @\"Pick Images\";
   ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```